# Is site first item in history?

Tags: javascript, browser-history

How to find out if site is the first item in history?
This doesn't work because of security reasons:

```
if(window.history.item(0)==window.location.href)
```

Comment: You've answered your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For security reasons the History
>   object doesn't allow the
>   non-privileged code to access the URLs
>   of other pages in the session history,
>   but it does allow it to navigate the
>   session history.

From: [Mozilla Developer Center: window.history](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.history)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot.

The users' browser history is private information and cannot be read using Javascript.